# How can I scale an image without blur in Unity Shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am a newbie of Unity shader. I'm trying to scale my image in the vertical direction. Here is the shader code I use:

```
Shader "Custom/PostMainCameraProcessShader"
{
Properties{
    _MainTex("Screen Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Param("Param", float) = 1
}
SubShader{
    Pass {

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct v2f {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float2 uv     : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;
        float _Param;

        v2f vert(appdata_img v) {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = v.texcoord;

            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
        {
            float2 uv = i.uv;
            uv.y *= _Param;
            fixed4 tex_screen = tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
            return tex_screen;
        }

        ENDCG
    }
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Here is the Image in my test:

[image]

And here is the result I got:

[image]

So Can anybody give me some suggestions that how can I remove the top blur and make the background pure black?

Many thanks!

Comment: so is this the output you want? 
https://puu.sh/FX8qF/a1c3847c7f.png

Comment: Yes! How did you do that?!

Comment: I just screenshotted your image :) I just wanted to understand what you wanted as the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, your image is stretching to the sides as you want. The problem is the image size here. You probably need to change the output image to be half the size.

The texture has u and v components, which stand for width and height basically. You need to halve the v value for your output texture.

One alternative way would be to try out [Texture2D.Resize](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Resize.html) or [Material.SetTextureScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTextureScale.html) in a C# script.

EDIT: So I checked a bit and it seems that it is not possible to change a texture's dimensions in a shader script, so you should go with the C# alternative I posted above.

Comment: Many thanks! Is there any way that the scale only works with the picture part inside the camera? I mean even the Image size is bigger, but the outside camera part will be ignored?

Comment: That's not how Unity works, what the camera sees is actually what the player will see, so parts that are outside the camera are actually "ignored" automatically.

Comment: Hmm, I actually don't know how to do that with a shader, but there are other ways you can do this. As a similar example, you can check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qd2em_ts5vs

Comment: Or, you can use the result that you have right now, and move your texture in the vertical direction using a C# script.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion gave me lots of ideas, I will do some further research. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi KBakeer, I found the way: return tex_screen * (uv.y <= 1.0);